# Deform Text Objects in Blender to fit into other object

Tags: text-object

I would like to take a 3D Text Object in Blender and Deform it. 
Such as that it fits **into** e.g. the outlines of Curve or Object. 
I tried with the deform modifiers cast and curve. But I could not deform it so the 3D Text is(and fits to) **within** the boundaries of another object (Curve or Object).

Thank you for your help.

Update:

Here a pictures what I want to achieve in 3D, but in 2D. 
[image: 2D version of what I want]

Comment: did you try `text on curve` option on the text object

Comment: thanks. i missed that. But that does not solve the problem. it smashes the letters into each other and I want that the letters are adapted to the space of the object or curve.

Comment: can please add an example picture to show what exactly you are looking for ( even a hand drawing )

Comment: you can try the lattice modifier but it is not that tight

Comment: shrinkwrap modifier maybe? Im not an expert on it though, I dont know if it can also shape something into the (flat)shape of a face or many.

Answer (score 4):

You might try the [*Mesh deform* modifier](http://blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/mesh_deform.html):

1. Add a cube around your text and subdivide so that there are vertices where you want control points  to be:

   [image]
2. Add a mesh deform modifier to the text and specify the cube as the control object.
3. Click bind and deform the control object in edit mode:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you Gandalf3. This is super handy to know. But first if I want to apply the modifier, I get the message, I cannot apply modifier to this Object. It binds correctly, but nothing happens to my text (so bind works, but apply not). Apart from that, which maybe is an error on my side that I have to find, it does not really solve my problem. It is better than before, but I would like the text to get the form of an object. In 3D and not modify in 2d. Sorry, but thanks for the tip, this will be very useful.

Comment: @user413734 you'll have to convert it to a mesh

Comment: Is there any reason or downside that you did not use a Lattice modifier?

Comment: @David I couldn't get the scale to match. I can never get lattices to be the right size..